# How to config SpringMVC with Hibernate and SOAP?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm creating a project springMvc + hibernate and Soap using web.xml

But my prob is when I start it with Tomcat 9. It awlays open a page that I dont define in my code. I dont understand why it's auto open. This is that page : http://localhost8080 :

[image]

This is my code:

[image]

File web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<!--
    Main configuration file for this Spring web application.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<!--
    Loads the Spring web application context, using the files defined above.
-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>services</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>services</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>services</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

File spring-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Config for soap -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.higgsup.internship.soap" />

<bean id="users" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" >
    <property name="schemaCollection">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="inline" value="true" />
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
                    <value>schema/users.xsd</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="UserService"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="UserServices" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="/ws"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!--<mvc:annotation-driven />-->

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<!--<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />-->


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.higgsup.internship.soap.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.higgsup.internship.soap.dao.UserDAOImpl"></bean>
```

File UserDAOImpl:

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public User getUser(Integer id) {
    User user = entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    return user;
}

public UserResponse show(UserRequest request){
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    UserForXML userForXML = new UserForXML();
    User user = new User();
    user = entityManager.find(User.class, request.getId());
    userForXML.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    userResponse.setUserForXML(userForXML);
    return userResponse;
}
}
```

File UserEndpoint:

```
@Endpoint
```

public class UserEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

```
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao;

@PayloadRoot(localPart = "userRequest", namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
@ResponsePayload
public UserResponse show(@RequestPayload UserRequest userRequest){
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    UserForXML userForXML = new UserForXML();
    userForXML.setUsername("hung");
    userResponse.setUserForXML(userForXML);
    return userResponse;
}
}
```

File UserForXML:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "UserForXML", namespace = "http://com/higgsup/internship/soap", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "username",
    "password",
    "email"
```

})
public class UserForXML {

```
protected Integer id;
protected String username;
protected String password;
protected String email;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

File UserRequest:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", namespace = "", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "username",
    "password",
    "email"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "userRequest", namespace = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service")
public class UserRequest {

protected Integer id;
protected String username;
protected String password;
protected String email;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

File UserResponse:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "userForXML"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "userResponse", namespace = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service")
```

public class UserResponse {

```
protected UserForXML userForXML;

public UserForXML getUserForXML() {
    return userForXML;
}

public void setUserForXML(UserForXML userForXML) {
    this.userForXML = userForXML;
}
}
```

This is the log:

> 03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.356 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M4
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 12 2016 11:39:59 UTC
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.358 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\hunghip.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-soap-hibernate-xml_2
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Setup\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.360 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.360 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.360 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\hunghip.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-soap-hibernate-xml_2\conf\logging.properties
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\hunghip.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-soap-hibernate-xml_2
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Setup\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Setup\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4\temp
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.7 using APR version 1.5.2.
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:00.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:01.851 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:02.726 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:02.816 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:02.981 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:02.982 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:02.983 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 3866 ms
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:03.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:03.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M4
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:03.248 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:03.260 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:03.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 279 ms
>   Connected to server
>   [2016-07-03 01:52:03,575] Artifact spring-soap-hibernate-xml:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:08.427 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:08.538 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:08.695 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Jul 03 13:52:08 ICT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:08.747 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.239 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.489 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.515 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>       name: default
>       ...]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.642 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.1.Final}
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.644 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment. HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.646 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:09.740 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager. HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:11.332 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect. HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>   Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
>   Hibernate: drop table if exists User
>   Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
>   Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
>   Hibernate: create table User (id integer not null, email varchar(255), password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:12.567 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@e760c3'
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:12.597 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:12.826 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.afterPropertiesSet Loaded ServletContext resource [/schema/users.xsd]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.105 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4567 ms
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.184 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'services': initialization started
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.190 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'services-servlet': startup date [Sun Jul 03 13:52:13 ICT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.191 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.234 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.250 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Setup\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4\webapps\manager
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.349 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.349 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>       name: default
>       ...]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.366 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect. HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>   Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
>   Hibernate: drop table if exists User
>   Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
>   Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
>   Hibernate: create table User (id integer not null, email varchar(255), password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id))
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.496 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Setup\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M4\webapps\manager has finished in 244 ms
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.583 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@e760c3'
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.591 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:13.620 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.afterPropertiesSet Loaded ServletContext resource [/schema/users.xsd]
>   03-Jul-2016 13:52:14.031 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'services': initialization completed in 847 ms
>   [2016-07-03 01:52:14,145] Artifact spring-soap-hibernate-xml:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
>   [2016-07-03 01:52:14,145] Artifact spring-soap-hibernate-xml:war: Deploy took 10,570 milliseconds

Comment: Could you please show the page's address from the browser's address bar?

Comment: It seems that a sample application is deployed with context root / on your tomcat server, i.e. what you see is not your application's page. Your application should be on http://localhost:8080/spring-soap-hibernate-xml or some other URL depending on configuration of your deployment. Tomcat uses /META-INF/context.xml to configure that.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it ? Which line I should change

Comment: I use Tomcat 9. I cant see context.xml

Comment: You are supposed to provide this file. Here is the reference:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: This is a too generic question, it will be hard to anyone find the answer for you.

Comment: How are you starting Tomcat 9 and how is the deployment process? Is it all done by your IDE? If yes, try to get support from the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally web services API generate a dynamic page, or in that case a example page, to list all configured endpoints.

Each endpoint is has a WSDL to describe the web service methods and the address a client needs to invoke the service. Like this: `http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL`

The address endpoint is in the end of that WSDL:

```
<soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"/>
```